# How to align text input with sorting button inside <td>?

Tags: html, html-table, alignment, textinput

I'm having bad time trying to align a clickable element on the right of a text `<input>` element. It wouldn't be a problem if I would have fixed dimensions, but the `<input>` will be inside of a container with variable size. The resizing will be made with a js function.
I need to place the clickable element on the far right, inside the `<td>` and, the remaining space to be filled 100% by the `<input>`. At this moment I'm totally confused and I cannot come with a clean solution that doesn't involve nested tables inside table cell.

At this moment, the clickable is `<a>` tag, but I'm not even sure if that's the best approach.
Need some clear advice right now.

Here is the basic code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            table{border-collapse:collapse;}

            td{
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 2px;
            }

            .container{
                width: 100px;/*this will be dinamically resized with JS*/
            }

            input[type="text"]{
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="container">
                            <input type="text"><a href="#" onclick="/*call myFunc*/" >&#9650;</a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        data1
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float the *clickable* element to right, wrap the `input` by a division and set a `margin-right` to it:

**CSS:**

```css
input[type="text"] { width: 100%; }
.wrapper { margin-right: 25px; }
.clickable { float: right; }
```

**HTML:**

```html
<a class="clickable" href="#" onclick="/*call myFunc*/" >&#9650;</a>
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/UrONaHU/1/edit)**